# I have a printer it do not print HP 2600 from Ubuntu 20.04. I have connected with a USB cable

Tags: printing

I have purchased a HP2600(all in one) after the printer HP F2200 broke down it was 15 years old.I have the icon when I print,tel me that there is a correct printer I click print but nothing happen.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

1. install hplip-gui {from software center}
2. open hplip toolbox
3. remove the current device show in hpliptoolbox {click on - button}
4. set up new device

It's gui based, You will understand next stuff.
It works for me on hp 1020. It will work for you.

Comment: Were do I find hplip-gui (from software center) I can not find it in Ubuntu Software

Comment: I have found the 'hplip' ( it was in download) but how do I installed it and were do I find 'hplip-gui' please help

Comment: sudo apt-get install hplip hplip-gui